# pyzbar module not reading supplemental bar code

Tags: python, barcode-scanner

Creating bar code scanner in python is pretty easy, however there seems to be an issue, that I can't figure out.  Periodical Bar Codes (Books, Magazines, Comics, and etc.) include a supplemental bar code to the main bar code. Look at any bar code on any book, and you will see a smaller bar code next to the larger bar code (see image below). Scanning that supplemental bar code is important in identifying the book. When I use the scanner it will provide the following output:

```
EAN13

b'0071001005998'
```

It never gives me the supplemental bar code.

(bar code = 0071001005998 supplemental bar code = 78959):
[image: Periodical Bar Code]

```
 # Site Packages - Install pip install opencv-python and pyzbar

#opencv - Provides real-time optimized computer vision.
import cv2
#pyzbar - Reads on dimensional bar codes and QR codes
from pyzbar.pyzbar import decode

#Read Video
#capture=cv2.VideoCapture(0) #0 - device index
capture=cv2.VideoCapture(0, cv2.CAP_DSHOW) #captureDevice = camera
capture.set(3,640) #3-Set Width
capture.set(4,480) #4-Set Height

#Turn Camera ON - True
camera=True

#Loop Camera Capture
while camera==True:
    #capture read returns 2 values success(1,0) and frame as data
    success, frame=capture.read()
    # Open Camera Interface to scan barcode
    cv2.imshow('Code Test', frame)
    cv2.waitKey(1)

#Decode bar code
if success==True:
    for code in decode(frame):
        #Print Proof to Console
        print(code.type)
        print(code.data)
        print(code)

else:
    #Camera Fail
    cv2.waitKey(3)
    print('FAILED!')
```

Does anyone know how to capture the supplemental bar code in python?

Comment: Sounds like a limitation of the `pyzbar` module. I suggest you contact its author.

Comment: Yeah I will probably let them know, but is there any other code\library that will decode the full barcode.  I am looking for some sort of solution.

Comment: [Asking for recommendations](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/393489/we-don-t-allow-questions-seeking-recommendations-for-books-tools-software-lib) is off-topic for this site. You might have better luck asking on [Super User](https://superuser.com/).

Comment: I know nothing about `pyzbar`, but have you tried running an image through it which contained *only* the supplemental bar code?

Comment: There was no information related to supplemental barcodes in both the [original](https://sourceforge.net/projects/zbar/) and [fork](https://github.com/mchehab/zbar) library sources. It seems that ZBar does not support supplemental barcodes.

Comment: Does anyone know of a library that does support this?

Answer (score 2):

Install the dependencies (on mac + python):

```
$ brew install zbar
$ pip install pyzbar
$ pip install opencv-python
```

You can define the symbols to ZBar. Please try this python code:

```py
import cv2
import pyzbar.pyzbar as pyzbar
from pyzbar.wrapper import ZBarSymbol

img = cv2.imread('barcode.png')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

barcodes = pyzbar.decode(gray, [ZBarSymbol.EAN13, ZBarSymbol.EAN5])

for barcode in barcodes:
    print('{}: {}'.format(barcode.type, barcode.data))
```

The result is for your image:

```
EAN5: b'78959'
EAN13: b'0071001005998'
```